# how to enter events for every third friday of every month in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, strtotime

I'm trying the code below to enter events into `MySQL` table using `PHP`. When I run it, it gives no error and no row is inserted into `MySQL` table. Where am I going wrong in the code?

Also when I change

```
$date = strtotime("third friday of $month[$j] $year[$i]");
```

to

```
$date = mktime(0,0,0,$month[$j],$k,$year[$i]);
```

it works for all days, but I'm looking for only third friday of every month..

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['myform'])){

         $day   =   array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31');
         $month =   array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');              
         $year  =   array('2011', '2012','2013', '2014', '2015', '2016');   

         $startday   = $_POST['day'];
         $eventplace = $_POST['eventplace'];
         $eventname  = $_POST['eventname'];
         $eventtime  = $_POST['eventtime'];

        for($i=0; $i<count($year); $i++){

            for($j=0; $j<count($month); $j++){

                for($k=$startday; $k<count($day); $k = $k + 7){

                        $date = strtotime("third friday of $month[$j] $year[$i]");

                        $week = date('W', $date) ;

  $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO caldemo(day, month, year, eventname, eventtime, eventplace, eventweek)
                         VALUES ('".$k."', '".$month[$j]."', '".$year[$i]."', '".$eventname."', '".$eventtime."', '".$eventplace."', '".$week."' )")or die(mysql_error()) ;
              }
            }
         } 
      }
?>   


<form name="theform" method="post" action="caldemo.php">
<table>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Venue:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eventplace" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eventname" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Event Time:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="eventtime" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="myform">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
for($j=0; $j<count($month); $j++){

  $date = strtotime("+2 week friday $month[$j] $year[$i]");
  $week = date('W', $date) ;
  $k = date('d', $date) ;

  $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO caldemo 
    (day, month, year, eventname, eventtime, eventplace, eventweek)
    VALUES 
    ('".$k."', '".$month[$j]."', '".$year[$i]."', '".$eventname."', 
    '".$eventtime."', '".$eventplace."', '".$week."' )")
  or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
```

Removed the third `for` loop. Changed the argument to `strtotime` and used `day` returned by it as `$k` in the query.

Comment: @MC_delta_T thanks for pointing out that `strtotime('january 2012 first sunday'))` would give wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
strtotime("$month[$j] $year[$i] third friday");
```

Where `$month[$j]`  should be month name  like `december`
and  `$year[$i]` should be year like `2012`.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

//showDay('january', 2017, 'friday', 3);
showDay('january', 2017, 'friday', 'third','text');

```
function showDay($month, $year, $day, $count, $type=''){

      $list = array(1=>'first',2=>'second',3=>'third',4=>'fourth',5=>'fifth');
      $dayname = $list[$count];
      if($type=='text') $dayname = $count;

      return date('d', strtotime($month . ' ' . $year . ' ' . $dayname .' '.$day));
    }
```